# Trying to Understand How Multiple Percent Symbols are Processed Around Variables

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, code

```
@echo off

set var1=hello
set var2=var1
set var3=var2
echo on

echo 2. %%var3%%
echo.
echo 3. %%%var3%%%
```

I have `echo on` so I can try to make better sense of the batch processing, though it really seems to be limited in parsing info.

When echoing a variable, are the inner/center parts processed first?

I'm trying to understand how multiple percents signs are exactly parsed when surrounding a variable.

I know every other percent symbol cancels out the previous one, but there must be more to it because I can never seem to get the result I think I should.

The logic seems to hold true when I do a simple echo using double percents %%, like so:

`echo %%var3%%`

`Result: %var3%`

The outer percent symbol is canceled, and it outputs with single percents: `%var3%`

So, when I use 3 %%%, I would think it would return `%%var3%%`, since ONLY the middle percent of the 3 %%% should be canceled, yet the result is: `%var2%`

So, obviously I'm not fully understanding how multiple percents surrounding a variable are processed.

When using 2 %%, does the 2nd % cancel the entire process of reading the value from `var3`?
Because how else could the result be `%var3%` rather than `%var2%`?

And b/c the extra % when using 3 %%%, it re-allows the process of reading the value from `var3`, which can now extract the value from `var3`, which is `var2`, and then simply apply the remaining single %s around it to give the final result: `%var2%`

Am I close or still grasping at straws? Any clarification or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This and a few other pertinent things have already been largely answered on **Nov 1, 2011**: ***[How does the windows command interpreter cmd.exe parse scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/7970912#7970912)*** and in specifically about ***[Percent Expansion:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/7970912#7970912)***

Answer (score 1):

So, using this batch script as an example, we can see exactly what's going on:

```
set var1=hello world
echo %var1% %%var1%% %%%var1%%%
PAUSE
```

CMD processes variables as they are sent to `echo`, so the output looks like this when it runs:

```
C:\test>set var1=hello world

C:\test>echo hello world %var1% %hello world%
hello world %var1% %hello world%
```

- **single** percent signs `%var1%` mean a variable name, so they get expanded
- **double** percent signs `%%var1%%` mean use a **literal** % symbol, so you get a literal `%var1%` as a result (`echo` does not re-expand the variables).
- three percent signs process like a combination of the above: `[%%]%var1%[%%]`, or after expansion: `"%" + "hello world" + "%"`.

Triple percents don't have any special meaning.

---

Note that `set` just takes everything after the `=` as a string. `var2=var1` will save the literal word "var1", while `var2=%var1%` results in cmd expanding `var1`.

Some syntax notes:

- [CMD percent sytax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html)
- [CMD set](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)
- [CMD delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) (unrelated, but another weird part of CMD variable processing)

Comment: @Io-oI It's outside the scope of the question, but yes. `call` runs whatever results after the initial expansion. If `var1=hello`, then your example executes `echo hello %var1% %hello%`. The `%var1%` gets expanded, and `%hello%` is empty, so the result is `hello hello `. Running `cmd /v /c` predictably runs shell expansion again, but does not blank out `%hello%` because `/c` commands run in an interactive shell instead of batch